# Convert a list of dot noted strings into an associative array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a list of strings that each contain dot notated values. I want to convert this list into an associative array with each segment of the dot notation as a key in the appropriate nesting level. The deepest level of nesting should have a value of boolean true. There's no limit to the number or dot segments a string can contain so the code needs to do some kind of recursion to achieve the goal.

Input example:

```php
[
    'foo.bar',
    'foo.bar.baz',
    'foo.bar.qux',
    'foo.qux',
    'foo.quux',
    'bar.baz',
    'bar.qux',
    'qux.quux',
]
```

Required output:

```php
[
    'foo' => [
        'bar' => [
            'baz' => true,
            'qux' => true,
        ],
        'qux' => true,
        'quux' => true,
    ],
    'bar' => [
        'baz' => true,
        'qux' => true,
    ],
    'qux' => [
        'quux' => true
    ]
]
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Or you just need us to write the code for you?

Comment: I need a little help with the logic

Comment: Please post your attempts what you have tried so far?

Comment: @JamesMorgan we want to help but you make it tough when you just put in a order without showing us your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` only solution.

```
function convert(array $input)
{
    $r = [];
    foreach ($input as $dotted) {
        $keys = explode('.', $dotted);
        $c = &$r[array_shift($keys)]; 
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if (isset($c[$key]) && $c[$key] === true) {
                $c[$key] = [];
            }
            $c = &$c[$key];
        }
        if ($c === null) {
            $c = true;
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: Suggest: [Getting/Setting/Unsetting array elements with dot-chained notation](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/185c00306b7d7d6a06d0)

Answer (score 1):

If you call your starting array of strings `$input`, the `$output` array in the code below is what you want

```
$input=[...]; //original array
$output=[];   //holds the results;
foreach ($input as $line){
    $keys = explode('.',$line);//break each section into a key
    $val = true;               //holds next value to add to array
    $localArray = [];          //holds the array for this input line
    for($i=count($keys)-1; $i>=0; $i--){ //go through input line in reverse order
        $localArray = [$keys[$i]=>$val]; //store previous value in array
        $val = $localArray;           //store the array we just built. it will be
                                      //the value in the next loop
    }
    $output = array_merge_recursive($output,$localArray);
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/LB03O)

Comment: `$output['foo']['bar'][0]` should not exist...?

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert($aa) {
  $zz = [];
  foreach( $aa as $value ) {
    $bb = explode('.',$value);
    $cc = count($bb);
    for( $ii = 0, $yy = &$zz; $ii < $cc ; $ii++ ) {
      $key = $bb[$ii];
      if ( array_key_exists($key,$yy) === false || is_array($yy[$key]) === false ) {
        $yy[$key] = [];
      }
      $yy = &$yy[$key];
    }
    $key = $bb[$cc-1];
    if ( array_key_exists($key,$yy) === false ) {
        $yy[$key] = true;
    }
  }
  return $zz;
}
```

Comment: This code will break if `foo.bar` appears after `foo.bar.baz`. You should check `$yy[$bb[$cc-1]]` value before assigning true.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pointer and some logic.

```
<?php
$test = [
    'foo.bar',
    'foo.bar.baz',
    'foo.bar.qux',
    'foo.qux',
    'foo.quux',
    'bar.baz',
    'bar.qux',
    'qux.quux',
];

class Test
{
    public $result = [];

    public function check($array){
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $this->change($value);
        }
    }

    public function change($string)
    {
        $explodedValues = explode('.',$string);

        $pointerVariable = &$this->result;

        foreach ($explodedValues as $explodedValue) {

            if(!is_array($pointerVariable)){
                $pointerVariable = [];
                $pointerVariable[$explodedValue] = true;
                $pointerVariable = &$pointerVariable[$explodedValue];
            } else if(isset($pointerVariable[$explodedValue])){
                $pointerVariable = &$pointerVariable[$explodedValue];
            } else {
                $pointerVariable[$explodedValue] = true;
                $pointerVariable = &$pointerVariable[$explodedValue];
            }

        }
    }
}

$obj = new Test();
$obj->check($test);

print_r($obj->result);
```

Hope this will help